# Sort main diagonal of array by Shaker sort

Tags: c, arrays

So that's my task. I don't know how to realize it in 2D.

All variables (i, j, L, R, etc. are integer)

```
    while (L < R)
{
    for(i, j = L; i < R; i++, j++)
    {
        if (a[i][j] > a[i + 1][j + 1])
        {
            temp = a[i][j];
            a[i][j] = a[i + 1][j + 1];
            a[i + 1][j + 1] = temp;
            k = i;
        }
    }
    R = k;
    for(i, j = R - 1; i >= L; i--, j--)
    {
        if(a[i][j] > a[i + 1][j + 1])
        {
            temp = a[i][j];
            a[i][j] = a[i + 1][j + 1];
            a[i + 1][j + 1] = temp;
            k = i;  
        }
    }
    L = k + 1;
}
```

I tried this code but I think that something is wrong with that.

Input:

```
1 10 5
4 0 8
8 18 3
```

Output: (That should be)

```
0 10 5
4 1 8
8 18 3
```

But current Output is

```
1 10 5
4 0 8
8 18 3
```

Comment: How is `i`, `j`, `L`,`R` `k`, `temp` and `a` declared and defined? How do you call this function? Can you give an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? Can you post example input? Example output? Expected output for the sample input? Example API? What is your question? [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: The output for your testcase is correct. The code isn't useable for anything except paper-and-pen-debugging, since it's incomplete. I.e. how are `i`, `j` initialized?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A function to swap values using call by reference.

```
    void swap(int *a, int *b)
{
    int temp;
    temp = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = temp;
}
```

A function implementing shaker sort

```
    void ShakerSort(int a[], int n)
{
    int i, j, k;
    for(i = 0; i < n;)
    {
        // First phase for ascending highest value to the highest unsorted index.
        for(j = i+1; j < n; j++)
        {
            if(a[j] < a[j-1])
                swap(&a[j], &a[j-1]);
        }
        // Decrementing highest index. 
        n--;

        // Second phase for descending lowest value to the lowest unsorted index.
        for(k = n-1; k > i; k--)
        {
            if(a[k] < a[k-1])
                swap(&a[k], &a[k-1]);
        }
        // Incrementing lowest index.
        i++;
    }
}
```

The main function looks like this

```
    int main()
{
    int n, i;
    cout<<"\nEnter the number of data element to be sorted: ";
    cin>>n;

    int arr[n];
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        cout<<"Enter element "<<i+1<<": ";
        cin>>arr[i];
    }

    ShakerSort(arr, n);

    // Printing the sorted data.
    cout<<"\nSorted Data ";
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        cout<<"->"<<arr[i];

    return 0;
}
```

The above code is written in `c++` refer it and make the changes according to your requirment

Comment: Sorry, but the thing is that it is a 2D array.

Comment: @Elgernon then just use `a[i][i]` whenever the answer says `a[i]`. The diagonal that you want to sort is the one where column index equals row index, right?